# Border around game preview window

Tags: unity, editors

I'm trying to put my game view and scene view next to each other, but the game window seems to have a border around the actual game view that I can't remove:

[image: unity window]

In the screenshot above, the game view should be touching the sides. I've tried changing the aspect ratio setting at the top to no avail, increasing the scale works to remove the border but that also zooms in so isn't a correct representation of the game. Does anyone know how I can remove this border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have "Low resolution aspect ratios" ticked OFF under the aspect ratio tab:
[image: arrow indicating where the "low resolution aspect ratios" setting is]

That should make the game view as big as possible, but the actual aspect ratio (e.g. 16:9) may still be leaving gaps on either left and right, or up and down. You can get rid of those by resizing the game window.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!